# Loop through Object in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, object, jsx

On a JSX file, I need to loop through two levels of an Object to render the information each inner Array stores. It looks something like: `Object > Object > Array`

My data is structured this way:

```js
const data = {
  group1: {
    subgroup1: [{...}, {...},{...}],
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

So I'm trying to acomplish something like this:

```
return (
  <ul>
    for (group in data) {
      <li>Group Name
        <ul>
          for(subgroup in group) {
            <li>Subgroup Name
              <ul>
                subgroup.map()
              </ul>
            </li>
          }
        </ul>
      </li>
    }
  </ul>
)
```

I know for loops are not allowed inside a JSX file but converting my object into multiple Arrays doesn't seem right either since I have no idea how many items might be coming form my API.

Comment: Isn't `subgroup1: {[...], [...]}` meant to be an array of objects `[{...}, {...}]` or array of arrays `[[...], [...]]`? That `{[...]}` syntax is invalid.

Comment: You can use something like `Object.entries(data).map()` to iterate through each key/value pair in the data, then the same thing for the subgroups, etc...

Comment: Jack, I've fixed the syntax. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: With the above mentioned Object.entries as well as [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) you should be good to go. On an unrelated note, given how nested this is, wouldn't it make more sense to use a table over a bunch unordered lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this using Herohtar suggestion, extracting the key/value of each of the parent Objects in an Array format:

```
{
  Object.entries(data).map(group => (
      <ul key={group[0]}>
        <li>{group[0]}
          <ul>
            {
              Object.entries(group[1]).map(subgroup => (
                  <ul key={subgroup[0]}>
                    <li>{subgroup[0]}
                      <ul>
                        {
                          subgroup[1].map(item => (
                              <li key={item.code}>{item.name}</li>
                            )
                          )
                        }
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                )
              )
            }
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    )
  )
}
```

I wish there was a more elegant way of doing this though.